# CI/CD With Jenkins and Wix: Can't Find Sources

Tags: jenkins, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I'm trying to use the [Jenkins Wix Toolset Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=80642239) to build an msi.  I've installed Wix 3.10 on the build machine.

The Jenkins job checks the project out of GitHub, which I can see is working fine.  There are wxs files, but it appears they can't be found.

I've installed Wix on the build machine and configured the plugin in Jenkins.
[image]

Not sure which directory it's looking in here, but configured Jenkins plugin to grab wxs source files via Ant-style file pattern \*.wxs:
[image]

Why is it that I see files (including wxs files) being added to the Jenkins 'workspace' but still Wix is unable to find them?

When the Jenkins build runs, I get the following output:

```
[wix] Enable Debug: true
[wix] Detecting environment variables...
[wix] Found sources: 0
[wix] Initializing tools...
[wix] Environment variables are not automatically added as parameters.
[wix] Environment variables are not automatically added as parameters.
[wix] Compiler found.
[wix] Linker found.
[wix] Starting compile process...
[wix] SEVERE: 0
[wix] Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at de.berg.systeme.jenkins.wix.Toolset.compile(Toolset.java:142)
    at de.berg.systeme.jenkins.wix.WixToolsetBuilder.perform(WixToolsetBuilder.java:164)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Build step 'WIX Toolset' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'WIX Toolset' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**[wix] Found sources: 0**   <--- CAUSE OF INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS

**EDIT 1:**  I've managed to get past this exception.  Turns out that my Ant-style file pattern of \*.wxs was incorrect.  Instead, I used **\*.wxs and it found the file.  Turns out that there's another problem.  In my wxs file I reference variable name like '$(var.SolutionDir)'.  Wix is complaining that it can't find this:

```
error CNDL0150 : Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.SolutionDir)'.
```

This is defined in the .wixproj file, but it appears that the Jenkins Wix plugin is ignoring this...

So how do I let the Jenkins plugin know that there's also a .wixproj that should it should know about?

Answer (score 0):

The path which you have given in the Source Files "\*.wxs" is not correct. Give the correct path exactly where your wxs file is present.